# Correct flipped boat in Stranded Deep

Tags: stranded-deep

I built a boat with a sail on a wooden base. After I found barrels I decided to build a barrel base. Somehow when I was building them while standing on my current boat my boat flipped upside down with the sail in the water.

I have tried everything to correct it, I cannot press e on it when it pops up to tell me to press e to interact, I cannot jump on it. I can not push it to shore.

Is there anything I can do?